# OpenVPN connection Time out after connecting to Server

Tags: openvpn, ufw

I have set up OpenVPN on my Server and now have problems when connecting to it.

As soon as the connection is established I cant use the internet anymore. SSH into the server is still possible.

here is the output of netstat -nr before:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 wlp6s0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 wlp6s0
```

and after connecting

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         10.8.0.5        0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 tun0
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 wlp6s0
10.8.0.1        10.8.0.5        255.255.255.255 UGH       0 0          0 tun0
10.8.0.5        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 tun0
SERVER_IP       192.168.0.1     255.255.255.255 UGH       0 0          0 wlp6s0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 wlp6s0
```

On the Server I have the UFW and setup the following rules:

in `/etc/ufw/before.rules`

```
# START OPENVPN RULES
# NAT table rules
*nat
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0] 
# Allow traffic from OpenVPN client to eth0
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/8 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# END OPENVPN RULES
```

and in `/etc/default/ufw`

```
DEFAULT_FORWARD_POLICY="ACCEPT"
```

I also added the rule `ufw allow 1194/udp`

These are the complete rules of my firewall on the server

```
Status: active
Logging: on (high)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), allow (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp (OpenSSH)           LIMIT IN    Anywhere
1194/udp                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere
```

Also when I try to ping `10.8.0.1` this doesnt work.

On the [OpenVpn](https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html) site I have found the following for this.

> You get the Initialization Sequence Completedmessage but the ping test fails -- This usually indicates that a firewall on either server or client is blocking VPN network traffic by filtering on the TUN/TAP interface.

This is the output of my local ufw settings

```
Status: active
Logging: on (high)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), disabled (routed)
New profiles: skip
```

**EDIT:**

I was able to test it on a Mac and the VPN works. Now I am clueless what the problem on my Computer could be. I am running Manjaro Linux with Kernel *4.4.5-1-MANJARO*.

**EDIT2**

After checking the logs with journalctl I have noticed the following lines

```
Mar 18 10:20:33 bla nm-openvpn[4638]: WARNING: 'link-mtu' is used inconsistently, local='link-mtu 1541', remote='link-mtu 1542'
Mar 18 10:20:33 bla nm-openvpn[4638]: WARNING: 'comp-lzo' is present in remote config but missing in local config, remote='comp-lzo'
```

So it was an error when using Networkmanager where I have not activated to use LZO data compression.

After activating this it now works and I hope this might help someone in the future.